# Jquery: if div exists on a specific* page do

Tags: jquery

I'm tring to generate a dialog(on all the site's pages) if on one of my site's pages appear a div.
More exaclty I have this site, and if you get a friendship request on your user page, I want an allert(or a floating box, I'll see that later) to notify you, wherever you are on the site.

I tried something to use if instruction 2 times:

```
if('http://'+location.hostname+location.pathname='/profile')
```

and

```
if($(".friends .new").length) {
   alert("You have notifications pending");
}
```

I got no results.

Answer (score 2):

In the first `if`, you used `=` when I think you meant `+`. Your `if` makes no sense anyway because a non-empty string is always truthy and passes the test.

As for the second, it will work if you already have code creating those elements. If the element is actually `class="friends new"` then you should remove the space in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could use append, and append a piece of JS. append will not fire if the element does not exist.

```
 $('.friends .new').append('<script>alert("Hello World!");<\/script>');​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

this will alert hello world if the element .new exists within .friends.

http://jsfiddle.net/dcqxr/14/

Comment: If the div .new shows up in that page, the alert should run whithin all the pages.